# Fiddler doesn't capture QT QNetworkAccessManager Traffic?

Tags: qt, http, fiddler, traffic, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am testing a QT C++ application using QNetworkAccessManager that is successfully making HTTP posts, but I can't see the posts in Fiddler.  What am I missing in the Fiddler setup? I understand Fiddler needs to be setup specifically for HTTPS, and it is, but I'm not seeing any basic HTTP traffic in Fiddler from this application.  Fiddler is seeing traffic from all other applications, including browsers, and other C++ apps like the Flickr Uploadr tool.

What needs to be setup in Fiddler to capture the QT QNetworkAccessManager traffic? I've also tried Charles with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you need to set up Fiddler as an HTTP proxy? Can you do that with this application?

If not, try Wireshark instead.